# Pagination with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, pagination

i'm learning python and scraping and i'm currently trying to scrape this page: [enter link description here](https://www.cci.fr/agent-immobilier?company_name=agences%20immobili%C3%A8res%20&brand_name=&siren=&numero_carte=&code_region=84&city=&code_postal=&person_name=&state_recherche=1&name_region=AUVERGNE-RHONE-ALPES&page=1)

I managed to get some data in my csv file with the below code:

```
from typing import Text
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
with open('scraping_5_pagination.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write("business_names, attestation, town_pc, region")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())  # initialise chrome driver
driver.get(
    'https://www.cci.fr/agent-immobilier?company_name=agences%20immobili%C3%A8res%20&brand_name=&siren=&numero_carte=&code_region=84&city=&code_postal=&person_name=&state_recherche=1&name_region=AUVERGNE-RHONE-ALPES')

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
agences_recherche = driver.find_element_by_id('edit-company-name')
# agences_recherche.send_keys('agences immobilières')
time.sleep(1)
region = driver.find_element_by_id('edit-code-region')
# region.send_heys('AUVERGNE-RHONE-ALPES')
time.sleep(1)
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Rechercher"]')
time.sleep(1)

for i in range(200): # Loop for pagination
    business_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="titre_entreprise"]')
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", business_names)
    attestation = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="lien-fiche"]/td/a')
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", attestation)
    town_pc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]')
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", town_pc)
    region = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]')
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", region)
    number_of_pages = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"suivant")]')

    with open('scraping_5_pagination.csv', 'w') as file:
        for i in range(len(business_names)):
            file.write(
                business_names[i].text + ";" + attestation[i].text + ";" + town_pc[i].text + ";" + region[i].text + "\n")
    
        number_of_pages=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"suivant")]').click()  
        time.sleep(1)
driver.get(url)
driver.close()
```

But i don't get why it doesnt click on the ext page button, idk if it's a problem with the Xpath expression, or with the implementation
Also, here's the the html code of the "Next button"

```
<a href="?company_name=agences%20immobili%C3%A8res%20&amp;brand_name=&amp;siren=&amp;numero_carte=&amp;code_region=84&amp;city=&amp;code_postal=&amp;person_name=&amp;state_recherche=1&amp;name_region=AUVERGNE-RHONE-ALPES&amp;page=2" title="Aller à la page suivante" rel="next" class="">
<span class="visually-hidden">Page suivante</span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="">Suivant</span>
</a>
```

Thank you for reading me

Comment: Can you try capital S in `find_element_by_xpath`?

Comment: try css selectors instead.
`driver.select("a[rel='next']").click()`

Comment: Doesnt work with capital S...

Comment: here's the message error that i got:  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="?company_name=agences%20immobili%C3%A8res%20&amp;brand_name=&amp;siren=&amp;numero_carte=&amp;code_region=84&amp;city=&amp;code_postal=&amp;person_name=&amp;state_recherche=1&amp;name_region=AUVERGNE-RHONE-ALPES&amp;page=1" title="Aller à la page suivante" rel="next">...</a> is not clickable at point (915, 699). Other element would receive the click: <div

Comment: It goes to the bottom of the page with the css selector but doesnt select the next button